# Why are logs left after removal of an application has occurred?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

I am struggling against the issue with wix toolset: why after I uninstall an application some folders including the "logs" are not deleted? is it a bug or not?

```
<Directory Id="logs" Name="logs">
<Component Id="logs" Guid="0A4D0A3F-2E0D-1B1A-1C6D-1A0F8FAAABC6" Win64="$(var.is64)">
      <CreateFolder Directory="logs">
       <Permission GenericAll="yes" User="Everyone" />
       </CreateFolder>
       <RemoveFolder Id="logs"  On="uninstall"></RemoveFolder>
       </Component>
       </Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes if the application you install generates files or folders after the installation, that can prevent WiX from removing the parent folder during uninstall.

If there are log files created after install, you can purge them by adding this to your existing component:

```
<RemoveFile Id="RemoveLogFiles" Name="*.*" On="uninstall" />
```

If your application also creates subdirectories and `RemoveFile` doesn't get rid of them, I would look into using `RemoveFolderEx`(http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/removefolderex.html).  This would require you to to create a `Property` and write the directory path to a place in the registry so you can set the `Property` before `RemoveFolderEx` runs.  You can't just use the `Directory` Id because `RemoveFileEx` runs before the MSI creates the `Directory` properties.  Read the link I provided if my explanation didn't make sense to you.

Hope this helps!